# Sprite Kit physics causes too much shaking

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite, physics

In my app, once the gamepieces are stacked to a certain height, the screen starts to move down to allow more room for building. The problem is that everytime the screen moves down, the gamepieces shake so much that they topple over.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        SKSpriteNode *gamePiece = [self pickObject];
        gamePiece.position = location;
        gamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

        [self addChild:gamePiece];

        _currentTouch = touch;
        currentGamePiece = gamePiece;

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

        if(touchLocation.y > 350)
        {
            _bg.position = CGPointMake(_bg.position.x, _bg.position.y-2);
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([touch isEqual:_currentTouch])
        {
            currentGamePiece.position = location;
        }

        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInNode:self.scene];

        if(touchLocation.y > 350)
        {
            _bg.position = CGPointMake(_bg.position.x, _bg.position.y-2);
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */
    for (UITouch *touch in touches)
    {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        if ([touch isEqual:_currentTouch])
        {
            currentGamePiece.position = location;
            currentGamePiece.physicsBody.dynamic = YES;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What code are you using to move your "screen down" ?

Comment: @sangony The conditional in both the touchesbegan and moved methods. I should have elaborated that it moves the background image down along with all of its children nodes.